# Searching through linked models in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

After following the railscast for creating a search engine, my code looks like this for search titles, and descriptions of posts:

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where("LOWER (description) LIKE ? OR LOWER (title) LIKE ?", "%#{search.downcase}%" , "%#{search.downcase}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

The post table, has_many tags though, and I'd like this search query to search tags as well. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      includes(:tags).where("LOWER (description) LIKE ? OR LOWER (title) LIKE ? OR tags.name LIKE ?", "%#{search.downcase}%" , "%#{search.downcase}%", "%#{search.downcase}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

This will do a `LIKE` on the `name` property of the tags. Edit it to suit your needs.

Comment: I didn't think it would matter - but the model has_many :tags, :through => :tag_joins... When I try the query you said it returns an error: "Mysql2::Error: Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous: SELECT DISTINCT...."

Answer (score 0):

Recommend having a tag_list stored on the post model itself, which will make searching trivial. @Dogbert's answer works just as well, the following contains the query to one table.

```
def post
  before_update :set_tag_list

  def set_tag_list
    self.tag_list = tags.map{|tag| tag.name}.join(', ')
  end
end
```

Then you can include the tag_list in your search query and not have to join many models together.